# How to use javascript-time-ago with react and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, redux

Hi I am creating a simple todo application using `Reactjs` and `Redux`.In the todo I have two property `todo name` and `time` .I am storing all my todos in `Redux` .Now the problem is I want when the user fetches todos it should like if the todo has been added 1 minute ago it should show like todo added `one minute ago` ,if the todo added just now ,then it should show just now added.Like that.Like in any chat application we have feature like this
[All my code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-swartz-1gdnb?file=/src/ShowData.js)

//Addtod.js

```
import TimeAgo from "javascript-time-ago";
import en from "javascript-time-ago/locale/en";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addTodos } from "./action";
import ShowData from "./ShowData";
export default function Add() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [note, setNewNote] = useState();

  TimeAgo.addDefaultLocale(en);
  const timeAgo = new TimeAgo("en-US");

  const add = () => {
    let t = timeAgo.format(Date.now() - 60 * 1000);
    dispatch(addTodos({ name: note, time: t }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={note}
        onChange={(e) => setNewNote(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={add}>Add new</button>
      <ShowData />
    </div>
  );
}

//Showtodo.js

    

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
    export default function ShowData() {
      const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {todos.map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              {item.name}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: "15px" }}>{item.time}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Your sandbox isn't showing items, and adding them doesn't seem to work either. And using time-ago is unrelated to redux or react, it just turns a date into a string. Please clarify the exact problem because I'm trying to fix your sandbox but it's not even half working apparently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that in `add.js` you are hardcoding the message that will be displayed later. what you need to do is to save the time the task is added to the list, and then calculate the the time elapsed from that saved time anytime the component is rendered. You can calculate the time elapsed using the npm package `moment`.

Make this change to `Add.js`

```js
const add = () => {
    // All you are saving now is the time this note was saved to memory
    dispatch(addTodos({ name: note, time: Date.now() }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        className="input"
        type="text"
        value={note}
        onChange={(e) => setNewNote(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={add}>Add new</button>
      <ShowData />
    </div>
  );
}
```

install the npm package `moment` using the command `npm i moment`.

Then import the package in `ShowData.js`
Make this change to `ShowData.js`

```js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import moment from "moment";
import "./styles.css";
export default function ShowData() {
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "50px" }}>
      {todos.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i} className="message">
            {item.name}
            <span style={{ marginLeft: "35px" }}>
              {/* calculate the difference in minutes */}
              {moment().diff(moment(item.time), "minute")} minutes
            </span>
          </li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```